# How to specify default formatter for custom field widget?

Tags: 7, entities

I created a custom field widget implementing [hook_field_widget_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_info/7), created a custom formatter implementing [hook_field_formatter_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_info/7) and also implemented [hook_field_formatter_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_view/7) to generate the formatter's display.

Everything works as intended (validation, persisting values, formatter) with one glaring exception: I can't figure out how to make my widget use my formatter by default.

Every time I add a an iToggle field I need to manually change its formatter in Manage Displays for that content type.

Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
function itoggle_field_field_widget_info() {
 return array(
   'itoggle' => array(
    'label' => t('iToggle Widget'),
    'field types' => array('list_boolean'),
    'settings' => array('display_label' => 1),
    'behaviors' => array(
      'multiple values' => FIELD_BEHAVIOR_CUSTOM,
    ),
  ),
);
}

function itoggle_field_field_formatter_info() {
  return array(
    'itoggle' => array(
    'label' => t('iToggle Widget'),
    'description' => t('Displays the field as an iToggle Widget'),
    'field types' => array('list_boolean'),
  ),
);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, as per Dave Reid's answer, it can't be done nicely.

That doesn't mean it can't be done at all (sort of), I found a decent workaround:

Implement [hook_field_info_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_info_alter/7) and alter the default_formatter of the Field Type.  Sure, its kinda rude because we update it for all ther Widgets of that Type, even ones that have nothing to do with our formatter.

That said, this is a very particular case (booleans) and it's safe to display the Widget regardless of the value.  Also its just as easy to go to Manage Display and change the formatter back to the old one.  It's a lot less disappointing than enabling an iToggle Widget and not getting the formatter. I think in this case the gains outweigh the losses!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is you can't. You can only specify a default formatter for each field type itself in [hook_field_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_info/7):

> default_formatter: The machine name of the default formatter to be used by instances of this field type, when no formatter is specified in the instance definition. This formatter must be available whenever the field type is available (i.e. provided by the field type module, or by a module the field type module depends on).

Comment: That kinda sucks, so I create an awesome new Widget but by default it uses a crappy old Formatter?  That's just not right...

Comment: Yeah in this case it's probably better to create your own field type so you can set the default formatter and widget yourself. You can make your field type extend another type. This is what the image field in core essentially does and extends the file field type.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I've been having other problems with my Widget extending Boolean Field Type and I've been avoiding creating my own Field Type but it might actually be better!

Comment: What are your options for Drupal 6?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you defined your fields. I created them in my .install file instead of using the classic hook_field_info. In my case for some reason hook_field_alter doesn't work. So i had to define my own field type:

```
function MYMODULE_field_info_alter(&$info) {
$info['MYFIELD_TYPE']['default_formatter'] = 'MYFORMATTER';
}//THIS WORKS
```

otherwise defining on an existing field type like 'text' would interfere with other custom types:

```
function MYMODULE_field_info_alter(&$info) {
$info['text']['default_formatter'] = 'MYFORMATTER';
}//THIS WORKS
```

Let me know if you have a better solution.
There might be a way to define it at creation type but dunno how to yet but so far all the solutions I tried were douchebags.

Comment: Thanks for sharing!  The solution I went with is the one in the accepted answer (which is pretty much the same thing you said!) :)